# Pyramid uWSGI logging in daemon mode is not working

Tags: python, logging, pyramid, uwsgi

I've been trying multiple things on this one, but with no success.
I want to save log to file (SqlAlchemy logs, app debug logs, stack traces on errors, etc.).

I'm starting uwsgi with the following command:
`uwsgi --ini-paste-logged myapp.ini`

And here is the content of the ini file (where *apiservice* is my pakage)

```
[loggers]
keys = root, apiservice, sqlalchemy

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_apiservice]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = apiservice

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s

[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/myapp-uwsgi.sock
virtualenv = /var/www/myapp/env
pidfile = ./uwsgi.pid
daemonize = ./uwsgi.log
master = true
processes = 4
```

The `uwsgi.log` contains only request log, without any actual logging data.

I've tried with INI options like:

- paste: config:%p
- paste-logger: %p
- logto: `file`

Nothing seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the uwsgi config section was fine.
After closer look at the `uwsgi.log`, even though the server was launched and running successfully, you could see an error:

```
ImportError: No module named script.util.logging_config
```

I've installed following packages to solve my problems:

```
pip install pastescript
pip install pastedeploy
```

Comment: Adding this for reference, it is also valid for Turbogears2